# Summing a series with a changing power

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}4^r$$
Hi, I was wondering whether anyone could explain how to work this out. I know the end result is $\frac{4^k-1}{3}$, but I don't know why or how to get there. 
Thank you :D

Comment: It is a [geometric sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_sum). See in particular the section "formula" in the reference.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply it by $(4-1)$. Expand without turning it into $4-1=3$. a lot of powers of $4$ will simplify except $4^k$ and $1$. Afterwards divide by $4-1=3$.

Comment: Actually, sorry about this, but I don't understand it completely. I end up with ([4^k-1)-1]/3 instead of ([4^k]-1)/3. Thanks :D

Comment: $4^{k-1}\times 4=4^{k}$.

Comment: Okay, but why am I multiplying it by 4? Is the equation for this sum $\frac{a(r^n -1)}{r-1}$, with a=1, r=4 and n=k-1, if this is the case, why isn't the answer $\frac{4^(k-1) -1}{3}$ The 4 here is ment to be to the power of k-1 but I'm not too sure how to write that. Sorry for being so slow at this :S

Comment: Woohoo, I understand now. I was thinking that n=k-1, but n=k :) it all makes sense now.