# $\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}4^r$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}4^r$$

Hi, I was wondering whether someone could explain to me how to work out the above series. I know it ends up equalling

$$\frac{4^k-1}3$$

but I don't know why or how I get to it.

Thank you :D

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the math.SE site.

Comment: This is not the right site for yiur question: see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203/frequently-asked-questions-for-mathoverflow

Comment: Okay, thanks guys :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432793/summing-a-series-with-a-changing-power

Comment: @Brian: Elise made the mistake of crossposting in the first place, and she apparently was happy to accept an answer here. If you feel the accepted answer is insufficient, you are of course welcome to post your own (on that thread, since of course we want to keep all relevant material together).

Comment: @Zev: Yes, I didn’t notive that it was the same person. That does change matters.